# Get a number after a Specific Symbol in JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a String Like This:

```
"Dark Bronze - add $120.00"
```

I need to pull the 120 into a float number variable.

How would I do that?

Comment: A string isn't code, would you be able to post the mark-up surrounding that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "Dark Bronze - add $120.00";
var val = str.match(/\$[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/)[0];
var f = Number(val.substring(1));

// (f is a number, do whatever you want with it)
```

Comment: I agree, using regex instead of substring/slice helps to protect against characters that could come after the the number

Comment: +1, but rather than calling `toString()` on the result, you should just select the first element `[0]`.

Comment: @Box9: Thanks for pointing that out (forgot to update that before posting)

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = 'Dark Bronze - add $120.00',
    toParse = input.substring(input.indexOf('$') + 1),
    dollaz = parseFloat(toParse);

alert(dollaz);
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2xqkh/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="Dark Bronze - add $120.00", val;
val = parseFloat(str.slice(str.indexOf('$')));
alert('The value is ' + val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Dark Bronze - add $120.00';
var pos = str.indexOf('$');
if (pos < 0) {
    // string doesn't contain the $ symbol
}
else {
    var val = parseFloat(str.substring(pos + 1));
    // do something with val
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Dark Bronze - add $120.00";

/*
[\$£¥€] - a character class with all currencies you are looking for
(       - capture
\d+     - at least one digit
\.      - a literal point character
\d{2}   - exactly 2 digits
)       - stop capturing
*/
var rxp = /[\$£¥€](\d+\.\d{2})/;

// the second member of the array returned by `match` contains the first capture
var strVal = str.match( rxp )[1];

var floatVal = parseFloat( strVal );
console.log( floatVal ); //120
```